# TCPDump output with no time stamps and IP and ports only

Tags: tcpdump

I would like to be able to see a very simple output from tcpdump
Usually it looks like this

```
12:17:35.906478 IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545: Flags [P.], seq 333440:333604, ack 2809, win 262, length 164
12:17:35.906493 IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545: Flags [P.], seq 333604:333768, ack 2809, win 262, length 164
12:17:35.906514 IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545: Flags [P.], seq 333768:333932, ack 2809, win 262, length 164
12:17:35.906537 IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545: Flags [P.], seq 333932:334096, ack 2809, win 262, length 164
12:17:35.906560 IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545: Flags [P.], seq 334096:334260, ack 2809, win 262, length 164
```

How to I get something like this

```
IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545
IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545
IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545
IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545
IP 192.168.1.149.22 > 192.168.1.2.51545
```

Note: the above is just an example. It is UDP that I am actually after

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this with `tcpdump` (it offers a `-q` option, but that won't get you there); however, if you're willing/able to use another tool besides `tcpdump`, such as [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), then you can achieve this.

For example:

```
tshark -o 'gui.column.format:"Protocol","%p","Source","%s","Destination","%d"' ...
```

(Run `tshark -G column-formats` for more help with columns.)

... or perhaps:

```
tshark -T fields -e _ws.col.Protocol -e ip.src -e ip.dst ...
```

Comment: Where to find all `fields` names ?

Comment: See https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters and https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/